# rendering array of models

Tags: backbone.js, rendering, fetch

Hi I'm searching from a particular pattern on server and I'm getting a list of models back.

```
 {"0":{"id":"20","name":"The White Tiger ","author":"Arvind Adiga","status":"Read"},
  "1":{"id":"23","name":"Tiger and the Apes","author":"Benny Rice", "status":"Read"} }
```

I initially tried to fetch the entire collection by

```
       var books = new Books()   //Books() is a collection name. 
       books.fetch({data: {name:'tiger'}});
```

but was getting undefined error.

So I tried to get an array of models.

```
   var books = new Book() //Book is a model name
    books.fetch({data: {name:'tiger'}});
```

I'm getting the array of models as i mentioned above.

How can I render an array of models in underscore template  ?  Is it really a very bad practice ?

Answer (score 0):

your collection response is incorrect, that's why Backbone isn't parsing it correctly.

If you are `fetch`ing a Collection than they should be in the format:

`[ { .. }, { .. }, { .. } ... ]` *an array of objects*

If you are `fetch`ing a model than they should:

`{ .. }` *single object hash*

So if you fixed the response then it will automatically get loaded into collection i.e.

```
[ 
   {"id":"20","name":"The White Tiger ","author":"Arvind Adiga","status":"Read"},
   {"id":"23","name":"Tiger and the Apes","author":"Benny Rice", "status":"Read"} 
]
```